# Power BI scheduled refresh is failing

Tags: powerbi, appinsights

I have a report that is published and also used by the client.
The data is certainly not huge (just 33k records).
But my scheduled refresh has started to fail for a week now. I have deleted unwanted tables and queries and still facing the same issue.
All of my data is in the cloud (retrieving data from app insights).
I even tried reducing the number of days for which the data is retrieved to just 10 days and yet I face the same issue.
I have also made sure the privacy settings are the same on the desktop client and on the report on the service.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: If it is a 502 Error I think its the source that the issue. I would try to a basic connection to the api you are getting the data from, has a token or other access method expired? does it work in PBI desktop??

Comment: Thanks, but it does work in the desktop.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869170/query-from-powerbi-to-ai-suddenly-fails-with-502-bad-gateway

Comment: Thanks, @AgustinPalacios, I am actually using API key and querying for just 30 days of data.
I even tried with 10 days of data and yet I get the same error.